# Read only objects produced by a factory in Java

Tags: java

In previous C++ code I've used friend classes when creating a factory that can output "read only" objects which means that as the objects are consumed throughout the code there is no risk that they can be inadvertently changed/corrupted.

Is there is there a similar way to implement this in Java or am I being overly defensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `final` keyword. This keyword can mark a class/methods as non-extendable, and mark fields/variables as non-mutable.

You will hide the default constructor of the object using the `private` constructor, and force parameterised constructors which will initialise all necessary final fields.

Your only problem is that the factory is kind of redundant. Since all fields of the object are final, you will have to use all factory methods at object build-time.

Example:

```
 public final class DataObject
 {
     protected final String name;
     protected final String payload;

     private DataObject()
     {

     }

     public DataObject(final String name, final String payload)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.payload = payload;
     }
}

// Using the factory
DataObject factory = new Factory().setName("Name").setPayload("Payload").build();

// As opposed to
DataObject dao = new DataObject("Name", "Payload");

// ==> Factory becomes redundant, only adding extra code
```

---

Solution without `final`:

I'm afraid you will have to forget about the immutability mechanism of C++. The factory pattern is never a bad choice if you have huge data objects (i.e. with a lot of setters), but you can't really avoid mutability of the constructed object. What you could do, is make the data object an inner class of the factory, and make the setters private. That way, ONLY the factory can access the setters. This would be the best approach for you (i.e. simulate immutability).

Example:

```
public class Factory 
{
    private String name;
    private String payload;

    public Factory setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Factory setPayload(final String payload)
    {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public DataObject build()
    {
        DataObject newObj = new DataObject();
        newObj.setName( this.name );
        newObj.setPayload( this.payload );
        return newObj;
    }

    public class DataObject
    {
        // fields and setters, ALL PRIVATE
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it could be poor design on my part but I currently call methods to "construct" the object. I found this was cleaner and more straight forward then trying to do it all within the constructor so I don't think using final will work here since I can only edit in the constructor if I understand the final keyword correctly. I'm building a hierarchical structure which I found hard to do in a constructor alone.

Comment: @Cube I'm afraid you will have to forget about the immutability mechanism of C++. The factory pattern is never a bad choice if you have huge data objects (i.e. with a lot of setters), but you can't really avoid mutability of the constructed object. What you could do, is make the data object an inner class of the factory, and make the setters private. That way, ONLY the factory can access the setters. This would be the best approach for you (i.e. simulate immutability).

Answer (score 1):

You can either put the object class and factory in the same package, and make the mutable methods package-scoped (this is the default visibility in Java, simply don't declare the methods to be `public`, `private` or `protected`), or make the class truly immutable and do all the work in the constructor. If you find that there are too many arguments in the constructor and it is difficult to understand, consider the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equal to friend classes in Java. However have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Answer (score 0):

If your object implements an interface and the factory returns interface type rather than the concrete type (which is better) then you can use **java.lang.reflect.Proxy** to create dynamic proxy at runtime that intercepts all method calls to the target object. As in the following code example **FooFactory** class creates a **Foo** instance (every time its **createFoo** method is called) but does not directly return instance but instead returns a dynamic proxy that implements the same interface as Foo and dynamic proxy intercepts and delegates all method calls to the Foo instance. This mechanism can be helpful to control access to a class when you dont have class code.

```
    public class FooFactory {


    public static IF createFoo() {

        //Create Foo instance
        Foo target = new Foo(); // Implements interface IF

        //Create a dynamic proxy that intercepts method calls to the Foo instance
        IF fooProxy = (IF) Proxy.newProxyInstance(IF.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { IF.class }, new IFInvocationHandler(target));

        return fooProxy;

    }

}

class IFInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private Foo foo;

    IFInvocationHandler(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {

        if (method.getName().equals("setMethod")) {
            // Block call
            throw new IllegalAccessException();
        } else {
            // Allow call
            method.invoke(proxy, args);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Foo implements IF {
    public void setMethod() {
    } // method that is not allowed to call

    public void getMethod() {
    }

}

interface IF {
    void setMethod(); // method that is not allowed to call

    void getMethod(); // method that is allowed to call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a C++ friend class in Java is package-private access.

`SomeObject.java:`

```
package somewhere.someobjandfriends;

public class SomeObject {
    Object aField;   // field and constructor
    SomeObject() {}  // are package-only access

    public void aMethod() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

`SomeObjFactory.java:`

```
package somewhere.someobjandfriends;

public class SomeObjFactory {
    public SomeObject newHelloWorld() {
        return new SomeObject() {
            {
                aField = "hello world!";
            }
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return aField.toString();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Anywhere outside of the package can see `SomeObject` and `aMethod` but can only create new instances through the factory.